# Foursquare data stream

Tags: foursquare

Is there an API for tapping into an anonymized version of Foursquare's stream of check-in data? Bing Maps has Foursquare Everywhere to show check-ins. Is there a way to tap into this stream of data?

We're basically interested in getting realistic location data for our research project.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://foursquare.com/apps/

It has links to the documentation